REXX in Mainframe TSO/ISPF how to capture JES2 Compile Output
My Rexx program accepts a value from the TSO command line when executing my Rexx program; the value is COBOL program name and then my Rexx program executes a JCL to compile it. How can I capture or display the compile output, specifically, SYSPRINT which contains if any errors are there. Currently my Rexx program after submitting the JCl Job shows the job submitted, that's it. But I want the program to show SYSPRINT output instead. The following is the Rexx code I have:
ARG_SRC_COM: PROCEDURE                       
  ARG MEMBER1 MEMBER2                        
                                             
  IF MEMBER2 = " " THEN DO                   
  EXIT; END                                  
                                             
  ADDRESS TSO                                
  ADDRESS ISPEXEC                            
  "VPUT (MEMBER2) SHARED"                    
  ADDRESS ISPEXEC                            
  "VIEW DATASET('#5220.DEV.JCLLIB(COMPILEX)')
                   MACRO(MYMACRO)"           
  "CONTROL NONDISPL ENTER"                   
  EXIT                                       
RETURN 0                                     

The Macro code is:
ADDRESS ISREDIT 'MACRO'                      
ADDRESS ISPEXEC "VGET MEMBER2 SHARED"        
ADDRESS ISREDIT "CHANGE "MEM" "MEMBER2" ALL" 
ADDRESS ISREDIT 'SUB'                        
ADDRESS ISREDIT 'CANCEL'                     
EXIT;"END"                                   

This is my compile job output:
JES2 screen after submitting the JOB
Compile JCL Output
After submitting the Job my rexx program takes it back to the original TSO screen where the compile request was made.

You need to use SDSF+REXX interface in your rexx.  Checkout these examples
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.5.0?topic=language-examples-rexx-execs

We don't have SDSF functionality. I have to use JES2 commands.

You could write SYSPRINT to some regular dataset instead of SYSOUT, then you can easily access it after the job ends. You would have to find out when that is anyways....

How do I write SYSPRINT to a dataset

Oh you mean to say in JCL write SYSPRINT to a output dataset. Got it thanks!

After I submit the job in 'MYMACRO' (see above) I am doing a 'CANCEL', instead can I go the mainframe JES screen to view the JCL output.

@user1906668 z/OS doesn't have a 'JES2' screen. Instead there are produces such as SDSF (which I think comes with every z/OS system but may not be configured), IOF from Triangle Systems etc.) which extract information from JES2 about running jobs and display it in a user-friendly format

@user1906668
You might start the 'STATUS' panel you used to show the 'JES2 screen after submitting the JOB' from your rexx.
Ex.
MYLIB = ' ... '
"ISPEXEC LIBDEF ISPPLIB DATASET ID('"MYLIB"')"
"ISPEXEC ADDPOP"
"ISPEXEC DISPLAY PANEL(STATUS)"
"ISPEXEC REMPOP"
"ISPEXEC LIBDEF ISPPLIB"
